# Naming conventions for Rust safe bindings

Tags: naming-conventions, rust, ffi

I am currently doing safe Rust bindings for a C library, that has a lot of constants defined in `#define` which have an `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` name.

For most cases it is not a problem (Rust uses the same convention) but actually, in this C library, some functions use them to give a type to a `void*` pointer, so I was thinking about wrapping them in a structure containing the correct data and use them as an interface for the user.

However what is the preferred way of naming those structures? Should I use a CamelCase name to match with Rust conventions or keep close to the C library names and use an upper snake case?

Comment: I'd suggest you check out the [proto style guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-guidelines), and the [rendered version](http://aturon.github.io/). If your case isn't there, the first link contains instructions for starting a discussion and getting it into the guide proper. FWIW, I'd vote to use CamelCase for those types, as I'd expect the code to be mostly read by Rustaceans. Isn't that the point of making a nice, safe, wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's entirely a matter of taste. Personally I split C library wrappers into two levels:

- FFI, as a separate module or even separate crate, which is as close to C library as possible, including its naming conventions and data types. In that case I'd keep `-> *mut libc::void` ([example](https://github.com/pornel/rust-lcms2-sys/blob/810c9b0f97f8a0302c608e04eea30970057b01ef/src/ffi.rs#L1263)).
- Safe, high-level wrapper, using Rust's data types and naming conventions ([example](https://github.com/pornel/rust-lcms2/blob/c340fad90d44f858681d8bd5f125914a6d641326/src/profile.rs#L211)).

Comment: Your first bullet point sounds very similar to the best practice of creating a [\*-sys package](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages) for C libraries. In that case it **should** be a separate crate for linking reasons, and it also allows other people to build on the unsafe code to make different high-level bindings.